# Bash script special character

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting, case

I am learning bash scripting, and I found this command in the book:

`` case `date +%a` in ``

Can someone explain what does + and a mean? I found that the % sign is there to check our output from the left to the right.

Thank you,

Comment: Shell syntax is extremely context-dependent; `+` and `%` can mean completely different things depending on where they occur. In this case, they have no special meaning to the shell, but they mean something to the `date` command, and it's completely up to that command to determine what they mean. Inside a variable expansion like `${var+value}` or `${var%pattern}`, they would modify how the variable expansion works. In an arithmetic context like `$(( ))`, they'd be math operators. In other places... other things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plus sign in this position means that the format string for the `date` command will follow. And `%a` is a format string that means: `locale's abbreviated weekday name`. See `man date`.

Comment: Whatever the script is meant to do, it won't work the same in different locales.